# Скрипт вставки данных popup в textarea по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form id="peredat-2"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
<input type="tel" name="vfb-27">
<input type="tel1" name="vfb-28">
<input type="tel2" name="vfb-29">
<input type="tel3" name="vfb-30">
<input type="tel4" name="vfb-31">
<input type="submit" name="vfb-submit" id="vfb-9" value="Отправить" class="vfb-submit ">
</form>
```

Как сделать, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку

```
<input type="submit" name="vfb-submit" id="vfb-9" value="Отправить" class="vfb-submit ">
```

все данные вставлялись в

```
<textarea maxlength="300" onkeyup="rcl_chat_words_count(event,this);" 
          id="chat-area-15" name="chat[message]"></textarea>
```

Заранее спасибо огромное за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#vfb-9").click(function(e) {      
  var values = [];
  $(this).closest("form").find("input,select,textarea").each(function(){
    if (this.type != "hidden" && this.type != "submit")
      values.push($(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val());
  });
  var value = values.join("\n");
  $("#chat-area-15").val(decodeURIComponent(value));
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="peredat-2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input type="tel" name="один" value="aaa">
  <input type="tel1" name="два" value="bbb">
  <input type="tel2" name="три" value="ccc">
  <input type="tel3" name="четыре" value="ddd">
  <input type="tel4" name="vfb-31" value="eee">
  <input type="submit" name="vfb-submit" id="vfb-9" value="Отправить" class="vfb-submit ">
</form>
<textarea maxlength="300" id="chat-area-15" name="chat[message]"></textarea>
```

Comment: Я был не прав, не все данные, а имя поле и значение

Comment: @Never3D а я что сделал?

Comment: Ага проверил, можно сделать, чтоб вместо & были enter, а значение name, можно было писать на русском, а то у меня кракозябры

Comment: @Never3D запросто :)

Comment: Отлично вообще, последний маленький вопрос, как убрать эти _wp_http_referer, vfb-spam=,_vfb-secret=, form_id=2. Чтоб они не учитывалиись

Comment: @Never3D Что это за строки? Вы отдаете себе отчет в том, что я не вижу Вашего экрана?

Comment: это скрытые input в форме. Как их убрать с вывода?