# Как получить данные формы и показать их на странице JavaScript

Tags: javascript, form

Есть форма, для ввода данных.
Как получить из нее данные и после нажатия на кнопку показать на странице?

```
<form id="MyForm">
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" id="form-name">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="name"></div>
```

Как вывести данные формы в div, при помощи JavaScript?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/778451

Answer (score 2):

ну вот самый простой вариант:

```
document.getElementById('MyForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    // что бы не отправилась форма. 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('form-name').value
```

})

можете заменить на document.querySelector('#id.class') - как в css

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('MyForm').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  var inps = document.querySelectorAll("input, select, textarea")
  
  for (var q=0; q<inps.length; ++q) {
    if (inps[q].name && inps[q].form === this) {
      console.log("%s %s", inps[q].name, inps[q].value)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="MyForm" name="my-form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="form-name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно программно повесить onsubmit слушателя на MyForm.

```
MyForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Чтобы форма не отправлялась
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = document.getElementById('form-name').value;
});
```